# Visual Studio 2010's SQL Schema & Data Compare - Can it be accesed from code?

Tags: sql, api, visual-studio-2010, compare

The other day I tried out VS2010's SQL compare tools and thought they were awesome.
I am wondering if there is any way to harness these tools in code written in VS 2010.

Comment: Can you specify how you want to "use" these features? Not being facetious, but there are different answers for different scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a MSDN forum [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1dc841f2-f5e4-4444-82b7-bb9fb9e31abf/visual-studio-2010-data-compare-automation?forum=vstsdb) about this. The answer points to this [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/psirr/data-compare-dte-commands) which outlines how to use this via DTE. It is targeted at 2008 but I would think it is still applicable.